# Using BabelNet in JAVA

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using BabelNet API 2.5 to get the synset of a word. The code for various purposes is clearly elucidated here: http://babelnet.org/guide#Mainclasses

And accordingly I write my code (In JAVA):

```
BabelNet bn = BabelNet.getInstance();
...

for (BabelSynset synset : bn.getSynsets(Language.EN, value, BabelPOS.NOUN,BabelSenseSource.WN))

            {

                System.out.println("Synset ID: " + synset.getId());
            }
```

In the code value contains the String whose Synset I need.

But I get this error:

'The method getSynsets(Language, String, POS, BabelSenseSource...) in the type BabelNet is not applicable for the arguments (Language, String, BabelPOS, BabelSenseSource)' with the bn.getSynsets highlighted.

I am using Eclipse to do this.

Can anybody explain the error?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the class **POS** in edu.mit.jwi.item.POS instead of BabelPOS.

import edu.mit.jwi.item.POS contained in jwi-2.1.4.jar and after you could write

```
bn.getSynsets(Language.EN, value, POS.NOUN, BabelSenseSource.WN)
```

The example code you have seen [in this link](http://babelnet.org/guide#Mainclasses) is for the latest version of Babelnet (3.0), not for 2.5.

Comment: I changed to Babelnet 3.0 and the error still persisted. Also when I downloaded the mentioned .jar file, imported edu.miy.jwi.item.POS and used the stated code I'm still getting the same error.  'Remove arguments to match getSynsets(Language, String)'

Comment: You must use POS.NOUN only if you use Babelnet 2.5. If you use Babelnet 3.0 you must use BabelPOS.NOUN. example:                                         `List<BabelSynset> slist = bn.getSynsets(Language.EN, "home", BabelPOS.NOUN,BabelSenseSource.WN);`